# Vector Blur Node not blurring

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-passes

I have a bunch of boxes flying apart in Cycles, and I'm using the Vector Blur node for motion blur. Nothing's blurring.

It's the simplest compositor setup: RenderLayer Image/Z/Speed goes to Vector Blur node Image/Z/Speed, Vector Blur node goes to Comp.Out and Viewer.Out. I've tried all sorts of settings on the VB node, but nothing changes. What have I not set up?

Blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8k6n3cr3wu2iwqo/logo_match.blend?dl=0

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Trying to remember how (blush)... Done.

Comment: @Carlo [Be careful when re-uploading .blends](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/827/599). In general it's probably not as important to upload question .blends compared to answers.

Comment: Uh, sorry @gandalf3! I'll carefully read that post. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the vector pass can't "see" through transparent (glass) objects; in this case all it sees is the `lens` object, which is remaining motionless relative to the camera.

To render with motion blur in this situation, you'll have to use Cycles' built in motion blur. Enable it in *Properties > Render settings > Motion Blur*:

[image]

And remove the vector blur node in the compositor.

Comment: Oh you are KIDDING me :( Drat, drat and double drat. OK, I'll re-do the scene and teleport the lens into shot once the vector blur's done its job. DRAT. But thanks :)

Comment: @OroborosNZ Any reason you need to use vector blur? Cycles blur should just work™ out of the box

Comment: Cycles Motion Blur does work, and well.... I'm just trying to shave render time, and Vector Blur's faster. I don't have a comp I can dedicate to Sheep-it, and I don't really have much idea around sending files to a render farm. So I'm doing my best to shave seconds, and finding my own line between "noisy output" and "artistically-intended, post-modernistic style" :P

Comment: OK, tried the lens teleport approach - but now there's a savage light dip when the lens goes in front of the camera. RAAAGE. Looks like Motion Blur IS my only option, or I'm spending hours/days trying to find out why a perfect virtual lens is also absorbing light =>:-[

Comment: @OroborosNZ The lens's glass shader color is set to .8 white. Setting it to 1 should fix it

Comment: You, sir, are a legend. If I'm ever within 500km of you I'm buying you a beer.

Comment: So what would happen if for some reason (eg. fast rendering lightsabers) you wanted to use the compositor to do motion blur and the objects are behind something (eg. a lens flare layer). Would it be possible to put the lens flare on one layer and the lightsabers on another layer and then exclude the lens flares so the compositor motion blur can still be used on the lightsabers? Thanks.